# Magento 2 - event observer called multiple time

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am using `sales_order_status_history_save_after` event for store data in my custom table.

I need also update comment with a prefix of `commentId (entity_id)` in to `sales_order_status_history` table.

While I am doing setComment data in observer than two times data stored in my custom table.

also, I have added log in to the observer file I found that my event call two times. I did not understand why its call two times and my data stored 2 times in my custom table.

is anyone knows how we can solve this issue??

here is the code:

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    try {
         $statusHistory = $observer->getEvent()->getStatusHistory();
         $orderId = $statusHistory->getParentId();
         $commentId = $statusHistory->getId();
         $post = $this->request->getPostValue();

         $oldComment = $statusHistory->getComment();

         $newComment = "Comment Id : ".$commentId. $oldComment;

         $statusHistory->setComment($newComment);

         $_orderstatusdata = $post['order_reprint'];
         $bulkInsert = [];

         foreach ($_orderstatusdata as $orderstatusdata) {
            if($orderstatusdata['is_reprint']){

                $customdata = [];
                $customdata['key1'] = 'val1';
                $customdata['key2'] = 'val2';
                $customdata['key3'] = 'val3';
                $customdata['key4'] = 'val4';

                $bulkInsert[] = $customdata;

            }               
         }

        $connection->insertMultiple('custom_table',$bulkInsert);

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $this->logger->error($e);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you please post your code here ?

Comment: @DharmendraJadav: I have edit question with code. Please check

Comment: @KetanPanchal are you able to stop calling 2 times events ?

Comment: Yes @sumeetbajaj

Comment: @KetanPanchal can you please let me know how you can stop to calling two times same event ?

Comment: @sumeetbajaj: added answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Prevention i have used **registry** in my code.

```
if (!$this->registry->registry('comment_save_after')) 
{
   $this->registry->register('comment_save_after', 'Executed');
   
   try{
   
   }
   catch (\Exception $e)
   {
       echo $e->getMessage();
   }
}
```

Let me know if you are facing same issue after using registry.

Comment: great it will help to others too.

Comment: great this help me